# Cannot open Unity Hub , something is bad with files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i wanted to start making unity projects, but i expirienced very strange error after trying to open unity hub:
[here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frDY5.png)

then when im trying to open this happends: [black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBzEC.png) - and nothing loading
i tried almost everything - deleting folders, scanning system nothing helped. I found some error in logs: {"timestamp":"2022-04-08T13:06:08.553Z","level":"error","moduleName":"App","message":"[\n  "Failed to start Unity Hub, reason: Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'E:\\Unity  projekty\\Metin2 ulepszanie jd\\hubInfo.json'"\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-04-08T13:06:08.553Z","level":"error","moduleName":"App","message":"[\n  "Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'E:\\Unity  projekty\\Metin2 ulepszanie jd\\hubInfo.json'"\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-04-08T13:06:08.553Z","level":"error","moduleName":"ErrorBox","message":"[\n  "UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'E:\\Unity  projekty\\Metin2 ulepszanie jd\\hubInfo.json'\n" +\n    "Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'E:\\Unity  projekty\\Metin2 ulepszanie jd\\hubInfo.json'"\n]"}

It wants to open a folder that no longer exist, cuz I deleted it while ago, additionally i have no disk E on my computer: C:, D:, F:. I dont really know how to solve this, would appreciate a support!

Comment: I would try and uninstall and reinstall UnityHub

Comment: did that 10 times